# PHP memory size exhausted in docker with magento/bin setup:di:compile

Tags: php, docker, magento, magento2

I got this error in log file after run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` or `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production` in `php:7.1-fpm` image's container.

> [2019-02-04 12:15:26] main.ERROR: /usr/local/bin/php -f /var/www/html/m230/bin/magento setup:di:compile 2>&1
>   Compilation was started.
>   %message% 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% < 1 sec 72.0 MiB%message% 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% < 1 sec 72.0 MiBProxies code generation... 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% < 1 sec 72.0 MiB
>   Proxies code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 76.0 MiB
>   Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 76.0 MiB
>   Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36864 bytes) in /var/www/html/m230/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/FileClassScanner.php on line 81
>   Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors. [] []

I tried to increase memory limit by running `php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:di:compile` or even `php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:di:compile`

This error doesn't occur if I use `php:7.1-apache` image (I use the same source code and database, just change image)

This error occurs on both my laptop (running arch-linux) and desktop (running ubuntu). I know they are strong enough to run that command.

My Dockerfile I used:

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm

# Install necessary libraries for Magento2
RUN apt-get -y update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libxslt-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mcrypt xsl intl zip bcmath -j$(nproc) gd soap

# Install xdebug
RUN pecl install xdebug
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on\n\
xdebug.remote_autostart=off\n\
xdebug.remote_host=10.5.0.1\n\
xdebug.remote_port=9000\n\
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

# Set memory_limit
RUN echo "php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 2G" >> /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

# Install cron
#RUN apt-get install -y cron

# Remove apt cache
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Create non-root user
ARG USER_NAME
ARG UID
RUN useradd -m -U ${USER_NAME} -u ${UID} -p1 -s /bin/bash -G root -o

# Edit PS1 in basrc
RUN echo "PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\w\$ '" >> /home/${USER_NAME}/.bashrc

# Change www-data user to ${USER_NAME}
RUN sed -i -e "s/www-data/${USER_NAME}/" /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In docker-compose.yml

```
php:
    container_name: php-server
    build: ./php/
    volumes:
      - ./..:/var/www
      - ./php/ini:/usr/local/etc/php // note that this line maps docker's /usr/local/etc/php
```

At your php Dockerfile directory under ini/conf.d/ create a file named memory_limit.ini
So your directory will be .../php/ini/conf.d/memory_limit.ini Inside memory_limit.ini

```
memory_limit = -1
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. But I still wonder why I can't use `php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:di:compile` directly

Comment: Watch out setting memory_limit to -1, it may cause a problem in case when memory leak happens :)

Answer (score 26):

### The Docker way

Confirm you are low on memory by running this command on your docker container bash `~$ php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"`. It should output `128M`. To increase, check if the `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/` path exists in your container. I believe it should if your php repo is build and maintained from the official Docker Hub.
If it exists:

```
~$ cd /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/
#create and or update a file called docker-php-memlimit.ini (comment)
#in /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/(comment)
~$ echo 'memory_limit = -1' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-memlimit.ini
#from the line below we setting memory to unlimited by using -1 (comment)
#Or you can set amount allocated by changing 'memory_limit = 512M' (comment)

# then check the memory with the following code (comment)
~$ php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"
```

To avoid running bash everytime you need to install this, you add the file to your dockerfile as follow:

```
#dockerfile
RUN cd /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ && \
  echo 'memory_limit = -1' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-memlimit.ini
```

If the docker build cannot change directory to /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ it will break. You can explorer from your repo other means.

References: https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/issues/447

Answer (score -3):

You have to change the memory limit for PHP cli in php docker container.